# How to find peak value in density plot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-analysis, density-plot

I want to find and draw the peak values of my distribution graphs. All the methods that I have seen online are for numpy arrays. How can I find out the peak values from a data frame?

[image: KDE Plot]

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,8.27)}) 
sns.set_context("poster")
g = sns.kdeplot(df1['actual_fee'], color='b', Label='Primary', legend = True) 
g = sns.kdeplot(df2['actual_fee'], color='y', Label='Secondary', legend = True) 
g.set(xlim = [5,700]) plt.xlabel('Fee')  plt.ylabel('Probability Density')  
plt.savefig("overall.png")
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide us a sample from your dataframe?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're working with `pandas` `df["col"].values` is a `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your dataframe to a numpy array (Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)) and use one of the methods you have found online for numpy arrays.